# Is it possible to call code from within a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a text-based game in python, and am trying to create a dictionary of possible random events, seen below.

```
events = {
    '1': text:'You find treasure in the chest', code:treasure += 1 
    '2': text:'There is a trap in the chest', code:hp -= 1
}
```

Is it possible to call the code linked to the event without using if statements or defined functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to write an anonymous function, rather than referencing existing ones.

```py
events = {
    '1': {text:'You find treasure in the chest', code: lambda: treasure += 1},
    '2': {text:'There is a trap in the chest', code: lambda: hp -= 1},
}
```

Now you can do `events['1']['code']()` to execute that block.

---

That said, consider a more object-oriented approach, where you perhaps create a player object and pass it in to the action, which mutates its attributes.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Player:
    hp: int = 10        # or whatever default
    treasure: int = 10  # or whatever default

events = {
    '1': {text:'You find treasure in the chest', code: lambda p: p.treasure += 1}, 
    '2': {text:'There is a trap in the chest', code: lambda p: p.hp -= 1},
}

player = Player()

for event in events.values():
    print(event.text)
    event.code(player)
```

Comment: It seems you can't assign values using lambda

Comment: @FrostWolf oof that's true. `p.treasure.__iadd__(1)` then :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Example

```
In [15]: def hi(): print("hi")

In [16]: def hello(): print("hello")

In [17]: func = {"hi":hi, "hello":hello}

In [18]: func["hi"]()
hi

In [19]: func["hello"]()
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use closure:

```
class Status(object):
    def __init__(self, treasure, hp):
        self.treasure = treasure
        self.hp = hp

    def __repr__(self):
        return "treasure: {}, hp: {}".format(self.treasure, self.hp)


def get_treasure_event(status, num_treasure):
    def treasure_event():
        status.treasure += num_treasure
    return treasure_event


def get_hp_event(status, hp):
    def hp_event():
        status.hp += hp
    return hp_event


status = Status(100, 10)
events = {}
events["1"] = {"text": 'You find treasure in the chest',
               "func": get_treasure_event(status, 1)}
events["2"] = {"text": 'There is a trap in the chest',
               "func": get_hp_event(status, -1)}

events["1"]["func"]()
events["2"]["func"]()
print(status)
```

Comment: It's unclear why a function factory is preferred here, but okay :). Notably `get_treasure_event == get_hp_event`

Comment: @AdamSmith 1. Readability. 2. Multiple lines. 3. Operators. 4. Statements. -- Using lambdas as event callbacks is a terrible design imo.

Comment: @JordanBrière sure I agree on all points (with the possible exception of the dig at lambdas -- while they are quite limited in Python, callbacks are literally their redeeming use case) however none of those things are specific to factory functions.Changing the signatures of `treasure_event` and `hp_event` and putting them at toplevel accomplishes the same.

Comment: The indirection of the factory function is what I was calling out, not the practice of naming functions